# Getting "make: *** [ext/gtk+/php_gtk+.lo] Error 1" while installing php_gtk on Fedora 17

Tags: php-gtk

I want to install `php_gtk` on Fedora 17.

I've downloaded `php-gtk-2.0.1` and tried to install it. Then I've done this:

```
./buildconf
./configure
make
```

After the `make` command, the following error appeared:

```
In file included from /home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/./ext/gtk+/php_gtk+.c:23:0:
/home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/main/php_gtk.h:307:64: error: unknown type name 'function_entry'
In file included from /home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/./ext/gtk+/php_gtk+.c:23:0:
/home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/main/php_gtk.h:308:68: error: unknown type name 'function_entry'
In file included from /home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/./ext/gtk+/php_gtk+.c:23:0:
/home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/main/php_gtk.h:490:64: error: unknown type name 'function_entry'
In file included from /home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/./ext/gtk+/php_gtk+.c:23:0:
/home/n/Downloads/php-gtk-2.0.1/main/php_gtk.h:506:66: error: unknown type name 'function_entry'
make: *** [ext/gtk+/php_gtk+.lo] Error 1
```

#### How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `function_entry` to `zend-function_entry` if you have php-5.4
But you may discover other problems, if this is resolved.

Comment: That should really be zend_function_entry (replace hyphen with underscore). And https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61479 recommends replacing "pval" with "zval" in the source code, but the whole story there is probably a bit more complicated. Simply replacing "function_entry" with "zend_function_entry" was enough for a simple test which I ran using the code published here: http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/